# how get values in <td>

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

with below code i just can  get value in  first  ? and i want get value of all td  tags 
to sum values of wage column  at runtime

```
//*************************************

@foreach (var item in Model)
 {
     <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () 
    {
        $("input:checkbox").click(function ()
         {

         if ($('input:checkbox').attr('checked'))
             {
              $(".wagein").each(function ()
                {
                    calculateSum();
                });
             }
            });
        })
            function  calculateSum()
                     {

            var sum = 0;
                        if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0)
                         {
                        sum += parseInt(this.value);
                        $("#WageSum").val(sum);
                        alert(sum);
                        }

                    else 
                        {
                            sum -= parseInt(this.value);
                            $("#WageSum").val(sum);
                            alert(sum);
                         }

                };
```

and it's my `<td>` tag that will contain many of values from model

```
<td class="wagein" >
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Wage)
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend getting the value server side, I have left out most of the table row detail to show you the concept:

```
@{
decimal total = 0;
foreach (var item in Model)
{
...
<td class="wagein" >
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Wage)
    total += item.Wage;
</td>
...
}
```

If you are still determined to get the total client-side, you probably don't want to add the JavaScript inside of your loop.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it server side and insert a row using a LINQ Extension model.Sum(x => x.Wage). Or you can do it client side. Look at this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cqmTt/) for an example.